# What is the best way to assign variables in a multidimensional vector using c++?

Tags: c++, vector, codeblocks

I have a matrix value like this

```
3   1   30
5   8   1
1   5   2
0   23  7
```

Currently I know only this way to assign variable to a multidimensional vector.

```
vector<vector <int> > vec;
vec[0][0]=3;
vec[0][1]=1;
vec[0][2]=30;
.
.
vec[3][2]=7;
```

For smaller matrix values this is ok but larger values this becomes harder. Is there any other way to assign variables in a multidimensional vectors.

EDIT

I am using codeblocks and I am getting this unusual error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


int main()
{


    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec = {{3,1,30},{5,8,1},{1,5,2},{0,23,7}};

    return 0;
}
```

error

```
error: could not convert ‘{{3, 1, 30}, {5, 8, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {0, 23, 7}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >’
```

Comment: Isn't that question _opinion based_?

Comment: What version of the compiler and what flags?  Are you building it in C++11?

Comment: I guess your compiler is just too old, especially the one in codeblocks is.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested for loops: Example being:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_SUB_VECTOR_SIZE; j++)
    {
        vec[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to substitute your given values where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array2d{
    {3 ,  1,   30},
    {5,   8,   1},
    {1  , 5,   2},
    {0 ,  23,  7}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do

```
const std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {
    {3,   1,   30},
    {5,   8,   1},
    {1,   5,   2},
    {0,   23,  7}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends upon what you want to do - the "best" way is dependent upon your objective. But using the example given in your question, the most convenient way is via `std::initializer_list` construction:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{3,1,30},{5,8,1},{1,5,2},{0,23,7}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the single dimension vector first

```
vector<int> vec1 {3,1,30};
vector<int> vec2 {5,8,1};
vector<int> vec3 {1,5,2};
vector<int> vec4 {0,23,7};
```

And then assign the 2d vector

```
vector<vector<int>> vector2d;
vector2d.push_back(vec1);
vector2d.push_back(vec2);
vector2d.push_back(vec3);
vector2d.push_back(vec4);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use manual initialization as in you original code, be careful, you probably want to use `vector`'s `push_back` instead of direct call to `[]`: since your vector is still empty, access via `[]` will cause segmentation fault.
2. If you have `C++11` use `vector`'s constructor taking an (aggregate) `initializer_list`. This can be handy:

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector <int> > vec;
   vec = { {3, 1 , 30},
           {5, 8 , 1 },
           {1, 5 , 2 },
           {0, 23, 7 } };
   ```

For more details see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Here I assume your matrix is in **Row-major** order, i.e. each of the internal `std::vector<int>` represents a row of the matrix.

3. Finally, IMHO the easiest way is to use a linear algebra library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/GettingStarted.html?_sm_au_=iRV5NTskZqkFv1nr) if you can. Eigen provides handy initialization methods: for example using `<<` (see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html?_sm_au_=iRV5NTskZqkFv1nr) for examples).

---

EDIT

---

**For you compilation error**: make sure that you enable at least `C++11`. If you use `g++` add `-std=c++11` to your compiler's tag.